# Method not found X509Chain.Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-8

My application works fine in local environment but does not work on the production server. I get the Exception "Method not found: 'Void System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Dispose()'." when running this code:

```
using (var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.RequestAborted))
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)responseMessage.StatusCode;
    var response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    context.Response.Headers.Remove("transfer-encoding");
    await responseMessage.Content.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
}
```

Here is my logfile:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
  Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver.com:8080/anything 
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HLCB1RVBIPJL": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Dispose()'.
at XControl.HttpRequestHandlerMiddleware.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\WorkingFolder\HttpRequestHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 168
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at XControl.HttpRequestHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\WorkingFolder\HttpRequestHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 36
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at XControl.XControlMiddleware.<Invoke>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\WorkingFolder\Middleware.cs:line 22
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
  Request finished in 2256.0938ms 500
```

Here is my project.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Data": {
          "target": "project"
        }

      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Configuration": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.Staging.json",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

My application i running in IIS 8 with .NET Framework Version: No Managed Code.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: did you add reference  to the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates?

Comment: Is there a reason you are still starting new development on .NET Core 1.1 instead of 2.0 which has been released half a year ago? Could be something framework specific, i.e. having an older verison of .NET Framework on your server in which the class doesn't implement .Dispose yet

Comment: Yes, the reference  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates is in the publish folder and with version number 4.6. The dispose method should exist in the 4.6 version according to this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx
I have installed .Net Framework 4.6.1 on the server.

Comment: That means you are running on .NET version less than 4.5. I didn't work with IIS for years, but as I remember there is some configuration settings on application pool which controls that. Maybe it runs on CLR 2 (so, .NET 3.5)?

Comment: I think have a theory now, the version number of the  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates was 4.6.2 but my .net clr version is 4.6.1. Can "windows update" update the clr version or do I have to install .net Framework 4.6.2 to get a higher clr version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to let windows update do its thing and update the clr version.